# does aws charge for stopped instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ***EC2 Instance*** Created on AWS server, I turn it ON only when I need to test something.
Does AWS charge use even if instance is in ***stopped***.

Answer (score 2):

AWS and most public clouds do not usually charge for Stopped instances.
There will be a charge for EBS volumes though as it remains attached to your EC2 instances.

best,

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @Saurabh,

I am using free tier,  Does they charge for EBS volume for Free tier instance if I keep it stopped? If **YES**, do you have idea how much they can charge ?

Comment: In Free tier 30GB EBS storage is covered. So if your EC2 has maximum of 30GB disk attached then it's fine, you'll not be charged for anything

Comment: Yes, as @HussainMansoor mentioned Free tier has 30GB available. So your 2 EC2 instances can go maximum of 15 GB each. For more details, https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all